# How do I apply an image texture material to a multi meshed object

Tags: uv

My gravel barge again.
With regard to the mesh plane I added to simulate the contents of the gravel barge.
The plane has multiple edge cuts so that I can adjust the 'height' of different areas to simulate uneven surface. As it won't be viewed close I decided to use simple image texture (image of pebbles) for the material. Trouble as I see it and have found that I need to select ALL the 'squares' which are created by the edge cuts to apply the material and enable UV mapping.
How do I do that? IN the image below I have applied my texture image as a material but it needs to be scaled in UV editing but I can't work out how to do that.
Blender file attached containing only the relevant mesh.
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume that by "edge cuts" you mean loop cuts? In Edit mode, just hit the A key to select All then U to unwrap as you would for any other object. If that's not what you mean you'll have to explain further. Incidentally the Blend file you uploaded is actually the .blend1 backup file and you haven't included your 'pebble' material with it. You can pack that into the Blend file via Blender's File > External Data > Pack Resources menu before saving and uploading it to blend-exchange.com.

Comment: Sorry got called away for a short zoom meeting. YES I meant loop cuts. I was remembering from another question I asked a few days ago where one reply used edge instead of loop. Sorry that I accidentally uploaded the '1' file.  I did what you suggested edit mode select A then U then chose unwrap then scaled and it works. Thanks What I did was what I normally do when uv mapping a single mesh - select, edit mode CTRL E select Mark Seam which I now realise is probably the reason.  I must remember that,, Thanks John (hey you 'got in first' :-) )

Comment: You shouldn't need to mark any seams at all if it's just a plane. Selecting everything in Edit mode and then used Ctrl-E,would have marked **every** seam on the mesh which meant that every face on the mesh would show up as a seperate island in the UV editor when you unwrapped it. Definitely not what you want! :^)

Comment: Yes I realise that now. My mind has been in a real tangle this past 3 weeks trying to deal with the loss of my wife. I'm getting there though .... s l o w l y.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh dear! I'm sory to hear that. :^(

Comment: @johneason  Hi John.  I had to leave this and now trying to resurrect it as I find that even without marking seams (on the plane) I can't get the UV editing to work. I add the image texture file (open after selecting Texture - Image Texture) and it displays but at the incorrect 'scale'. I have tried this and that but can't get it to work. What are the steps after selecting the image texture file?

Comment: added later   I think perhaps the fact that I did a mark seam before somehow it has 'stuck' even though I tried 'clear seam'.

Comment: Hover the mouse over the UV editor, select All (hit 'A') and S to scale just like in the 3D view. Don't worry that the UV image scales outside the size of the image.   You should really follow a YT tutorial on UV unwrapping. There are hundreds online. Although it's for Blender 2.8, [this](https://youtu.be/Y7M-B6xnaEM) is the official Blender tutorial about UV unwrapping and the technique is still the same in 3.6.  For your later comment, on that particular object you can simply select All in Edit mode and then right-click > Clear Seam to remove all the seams at once.

Comment: @johneason Thanks John   Where I originally became 'unstuck' was when I incorrectly 'mark seam;' on a plane.  I have always used 'mark seam' before but that was with angled faces  a cube benig a simple 6 faced object.
(